# Passing String from Array to Function Pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, function

Could any one help me with a problem with my code i cant see. I have an array of string i want to be displayed.  a variable that increaments and decreaments and want the string passed to the function.  The problem is the Whole string i want is not being passed though

i.e. ucMainMenu = 1 MenuString[1] = "TIME" DisplayString("TIME")

```
const char MenuString[6][8] = {"UNITS", "TIME", "DATE", "PRINT", "BTOOTH", "SERVICE"};

void main
{
   ucMainMenu++; //variable changing
   DisplayString(MenuString[ucMainMenu]);  //look up variable in array pass string to function
}

void DisplayString(char *cDisplayString)
{
 //do stuff with string
}
```

Comment: And *what* is the problem? Are we supposed to just know?

Comment: Arg should be `const`, not mentioning other more obvious omissions.

Comment: Also you should probably use `int main()` as the signature for your main method.

Comment: Post the actual code, not an approximation - the above won't even compile.

Comment: Make sure your `ucMainMenu` is initialized to an appropriate value before incrementing it and using it, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
const char MenuString[6][8] = {"UNITS", "TIME", "DATE", "PRINT", "BTOOTH", "SERVICE"};

void DisplayString(const char *cDisplayString)
{
 //do stuff with string
    printf("%s", cDisplayString);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    int ucMainMenu = 1;
    DisplayString(MenuString[ucMainMenu]);  //look up variable in array pass string to function

    getchar();

}
```

Read about initialization in C [here](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/initialization.html)

Hope it helps!

Comment: @Adey22 select this or any other as the selected answer (green check) if they helped.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a const char* pointer ...

```
void DisplayString( const char *cDisplayString)
{
   //do stuff with string
}
```